# Scala nested wildcard placeholders

Tags: scala

I've got a two dimensional Array in Scala made with

```
val arr = Array(Array())
```

And I want to make safe extraction out of it with Option. I wanted to use wildcards, but while this works:

```
def get(x:Int, y: Int) = arr lift x flatMap { _ lift y map { a=>a } }
```

This doesn't

```
def get(x:Int, y: Int) = arr lift x flatMap { _ lift y map { _ } }
```

Can anyone explain to me what is the difference?

Comment: Why do you need the extra `map` operation at the end? Looks like all you need is the `_ lift y`

Comment: Wow. You're right! I just overextended the maps

Answer (score 1):

`_` by itself doesn't expand to `x => x` or `identity`

What you might want to use instead is the `identity` predef:

```
def get(x: Int, y: Int) = arr lift x flatMap { _ lift y map {identity} }
```

See the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-expressions.html) section 6.23.1.